# Issue with the history mode Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have created a vue js project and my routing I choose the history mode. But each time I enter for example the link http://localhost:8081/, I get http://localhost:8081/#/ instead. Please can somebody help me?

Here is my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "front",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
 "build": "vue-cli-service build",
 "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"@websanova/vue-auth": "^2.21.14-beta",
"axios": "^0.21.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-axios": "^3.2.0",
"vue-headful": "^2.1.0",
"vue-lodash": "^2.1.2",
"vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
"vuebar": "0.0.20",
"vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
"vuetify": "^1.5.5",
"vuex": "^3.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "eslint": "^6.7.2",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
  "prettier": "^1.19.1",
  "sass": "^1.19.0",
  "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
  "stylus": "^0.54.8",
  "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
  "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
  "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"root": true,
"env": {
  "node": true
},
"extends": [
  "plugin:vue/essential",
  "eslint:recommended",
  "@vue/prettier"
],
"parserOptions": {
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
},
"rules": {}
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not dead"
]
}
```

Here is my routing file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
{
path: "/",
name: "Home",
component: Home
},
{
path: "/about",
name: "About",
// route level code-splitting
// this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
// which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
component: () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue")
}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: "history",
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Does it work in incognito window? [Can you check](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/tools-for-pwa-developers#inspect_the_service_worker) if any previous service worker is active

Comment: Mat J there is no previous service worker active

Comment: It happened to me as well, on dev, but it seem to still work properly. How does this affect you?

Comment: Narxx i think it is was causes this error : Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/".